# Problems with diacritics on vnc-viewer under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I have an iMac desktop and a Mac Mini, both running under OS Lion, and both under my local network WiFi (iMac with a cable and Mini on WiFi).  I configured "Screen sharing" on the Mini and installed the TightVNC Viewer version 1.3.10 on the iMac.  When I invoke the vncviewer on the iMac, it connects fine and I am able to do everything I need. The only problem are the keys used for diacritics (accents): none of them work! The keyboard of my iMac (standard Apple keyboard) is configured as "U.S. International PC", so that when I type on the iMac, for instance, the two keys '^a' I get the character 'â' (a with circumflex). If I want the character '~' I press the keys ~ and a space. I chose the same keyboard option for my Mini, but these special keys are completely dead and I can't get any accented letters, or even worse, I can't type personal URLs which include ~.

Any hints on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using VNC ? Why not use the built-in Screen Sharing app if you are sharing between two macs ? You will probably get much better integration.

Comment: Great suggestion -- I did not know about this app.